# Removing all instances of an object variable

Tags: java, object, reference, attributes

Is there a way to remove all references to a particular object in Java?

As an example...a `tutor` object has an attribute of type `Student`, called `myTutee`.

If I'm then working in a method `removeTutee` which uses a `Student` as the parameter, is there any way I can drop the value of the `myTutee` attribute from the `tutor` object, without using `setTutee`?

Hope I've managed to explain what I'm trying to achieve, reasonably well. Many thanks in advance!

```
tutor.java

protected Student myTutee;

public int getTuteeId() {
     return this.myTutee.getId();
}

public void setTutee(Student x) {
     this.myTutee = x;
}
```

...

```
student.java

protected int studentId;

public int getId() {
    return this.studentId;
}
```

...

```
classRoom.java

public void removeTutee(Student x) {
     // can't reference any Tutor objects directly from here
     // aiming to replicate tutor.setTutee(null)
     // by only referring to Student x
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do `x.setTutee(null);`?

Comment: @brso05 Students can't access the `setTutee` method, maybe I've over-simplified but I was hoping for a way to drop the Student object from `myTutee`, without using `setTutee`.

Comment: You'll have to do something equivalent to that, there's no other way.

Comment: that's impossible, since you are trying to set null on an attribute of an instance of tutor. you need that instance first, then apply this.myTutee=null in a method or use the setter

Comment: @user2839573 the only thing I can think of is create a new instance of Student with everything the same except `myTutee = null` in the constructor and return the new instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove a student from a tutor (set it to `null`) without having a reference to the tutor object. If you want to achieve this maybe your [ER model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) is wrong. Think if the `Tutor` is linked to the `Student` class, you could do `x.setTutee(null)`, which also sounds better. Also have a look to ORM strategies.

If you only have the student you need in some way to get at least the `List` of tutor of the class. In this way you can do:

```
public void removeTutee(Student x) {
    for(Tutor t: tutorList){
        if(t.getStudent().getId() == x.getId()){
            t.setTutee(null);
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```